# How do I define multiple responder flows, each in a different CorDapp?

Tags: corda

In Corda, I want to create several different versions of a responder flow, each to be used by a different node.

To do so, I understand that I need to define each responder flow in a separate CorDapp. However, they also all need to depend on the initiating flow class via the `InitiatedBy` annotation.

How can I structure the CorDapps containing the different implementations of the responder flow so that they all depend on this common initiating flow, without including all the responder flows in the same CorDapp where I defined the initiating flow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the question comes that,

> Why owner of **CorDapp1** shares their business Flow logic
>   to other?  What if the business wants to keep flow implementation codebase private to them?

**I think the following would be the project structure and implementation:**

Ex. I have three parties PartyA, PartyB, PartyC and each has their own version of  CorDapp's.

1. **cordapp-contract-states**  - this CorDapp contains shared `contract`, `states`, and `abstract initiating flows` will be used by `counter-parties` to implement their `responder flow logic`. *This CorDapp shared with all required counterparties.*

   @InitiatingFlow
   abstract class CreateTradeBaseFlow : FlowLogic {

   }
2. **cordapp-partyA** - this CorDapp contains `FlowLogic` implementation for create trade.

   `@StartableByRPC
   class CreateTradeFlow : CreateTradeBaseFlow {
      //Actual implementation of initiator flow goes here...
   }`
3. **cordapp-partyB** - this CorDapp contain responder flow for `CreateTradeFlow` and other business specific flowlogic implementation.

   `@InitiatedBy(CreateTradeBaseFlow::class)
   class ResponderPartyB(private val otherSideSession: FlowSession) : FlowLogic<SignedTransaction>() {
       //implementation of responder flow goes here...
   }`
4. **cordapp-partyC** - this CorDapp contain responder flow for `CreateTradeFlow` and other business specific flowlogic implementation.

   `@InitiatedBy(CreateTradeBaseFlow::class)
   class ResponderPartyC(private val otherSideSession: FlowSession) : FlowLogic<SignedTransaction>() {
       //implementation of responder flow goes here...
   }`

What's your thought?

Answer (score 4):

You need to define the CorDapp containing the initiating flow first, then set this CorDapp as a dependency for each CorDapp containing a responder flow. See https://docs.corda.net/cordapp-build-systems.html#dependencies-on-other-cordapps for details.

For example, suppose **CorDapp 1** defines the following initiating flow:

```
@InitiatingFlow
@StartableByRPC
class Initiator : FlowLogic<Unit>() {
    ...
}
```

Then you have **CorDapp 2A** which defines the following responder flow:

```
@InitiatedBy(Initiator::class)
@StartableByRPC
class ResponderA : FlowLogic<Unit>() {
    ...
}
```

And **CorDapp 2B** which defines the following responder flow:

```
@InitiatedBy(Initiator::class)
@StartableByRPC
class ResponderB : FlowLogic<Unit>() {
    ...
}
```

**CorDapp 2A** and **CorDapp 2B** would then need a dependency in their build.gradle files making these CorDapps depend on **CorDapp 1**, where the initiating flow is defined.