# how to invoke two different responder flows from the same parent flow?

Tags: corda

I want to implement a use case where two responder flows (different classes) are initiated by the same parent flow.

I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.flow.initialFlows.InitialFlow has been specified as the initiating flow by both com.flow.responder.Responder1 and com.flow.responder2.Responder2
```

in [How can I test two different responder flows in the same CorDapp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48790458/how-can-i-test-two-different-responder-flows-in-the-same-cordapp) the suggestion was to use `setCordappPackages()`. this method is used in test scenarios and is part of the corda test package. what can you use outside test scenarios?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I define multiple responder flows, each in a different CorDapp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48624039/how-do-i-define-multiple-responder-flows-each-in-a-different-cordapp)

Answer (score 0):

A single node cannot have two responder flows registered for the same initiating flow.

This is by design. Otherwise, the responding node know which of the two flows to invoke.

Comment: How do I work around it then if my business process requires communicating with multiple parties?

Comment: Do the different parties need to respond with different responder flows, or the same one?

Comment: Different responder flows. My current solution is creating a separate sub-flow for communication with each party, but it is super tedious